# Dynamic multi-column group of elements

Tags: css

I am trying to make a dynamic multi-column layout that can display tiles dynamically.

What I have currently:

[image]

Current style properties of each tile:

```
border: 0px dashed #CECECE;
background-color: #F0F0F0;
padding: 20px;
margin: 5px 10px 5px 0px;
width: 100px;
min-height: 100px;
float: left;
border-radius: 20px;
display:inline-block;
```

The problem with this is that, as you can see, when one of the divs is taller than the others, the elements on the next line start to the right of it, when what I want them to do is find the closest location to the top left.

This is what I would like it to look like: http://kcarlisle.tumblr.com/archive

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this with floats. I'm not entirely clear what layout you are trying to achieve though.

Comment: This is what I would like it to look like: http://kcarlisle.tumblr.com/archive

Comment: Can't be sure but I suspect you need something like [**Masonry.js**](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Add that as an answer and I'll accept it. That worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On looking at your example it does appear that this cannot be achieved using floats.

I suggest you look into a JAvascript alternative such as [**Masonry.js**](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Link - http://masonry.desandro.com/